# Togglebutton in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, css, togglebutton

I am trying to create a togglebutton for a website with Microsoft Visual Studio and am not sure if this would be the correct code to apply. I am working in C#, so the button is going to be generated in C# (and a bit of jquery) code and eventually styled in CSS. This is my code:

```
// Toggle menu oToggleMenuControl
HtmlGenericControl oToggleMenuControl = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
oToggleMenuControl.Attributes.Add("class", "ToggleButton");
this.Controls.Add(oToggleMenuControl);

string sToggleButton = string.Format(@"
    $( '.ToggleButton' ).click(function () {
        $( '#RootTabRowMenu' ).toggle( 'slow', function() {
        });
    });"
);

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ToggleButton" 
    + sToggleButton, true);
```

It won't be flawless, since I'm a beginner at this. However, I have noticed at least one thing that doesn't work the way I intended it to work. The last line contains the "Page" class. It is not recognized and it won't turn green.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: where is this code being run?

Comment: Do you mean in what kind of file? Then I could say it is running in WebPart.Master. It is a WebControl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the correct code is without + but , near ToggleButton

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "ToggleButton" , sToggleButton, true);
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed the error. Page is still black though, let's see if this works anyways...

Comment: There is still an error occuring, it's about the string keyword. Visual Studio says input string is incorrect...?

Comment: which linecode? at runtime or building the application?

Comment: At the line with the last bracket and semicolon under the jquery block (line 11 in code above), while at runtime.

Comment: delete string.format. could be string sToggleButton = @"...
delete ); at the end of line code and substitute with only ;

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work, but now the button's function isn't working the way I told it to. If I click on the button, it should hide the menu, while it doesn't.

Comment: check your html. in this fiddle seems work http://jsfiddle.net/xfn6d/
I suggest if possible to not use RegisterClientScriptBlock for register script but include file js into the page

Comment: you haven't include jquery in the fiddle. include with dropdownlist on the left. Also include jquery in your page.

Comment: It seemed like jquery wasn't included in the .cs file provided. Thanks for the help everyone. My code is working correctly now.